# Microcontroller with rotary encoder and bluetooth capabilities

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller

I am looking for advice on (what to use/how to make) a rotary encoder that I can connect to through bluetooth. I am writing an app that needs to display on screen in real time to the user the number of rotations as they are turning it. Also, I need to have the micro-controller record the revolutions per day so I can keep track of revolutions if their computer is asleep.

Criteria:

1. Must be stand alone
2. Has to be bluetooth compatible with a pc, mac, android and iphone.
3. Has to be able to store up to 7 days of data (this would be a very small amount of data, just the number of rotations per day and the timestamp).
4. Has to be small and cheep.

I was thinking a microcontroller with just a rotary encoder and bluetooth capabilities.

I have seen microcontroller like the Arduino and think they would be good to start with but I was looking for something that could actually be used in a final product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: About how many revolutions per day are you expecting to see (maximum)?

Answer (score 0):

Arduino is nothing but a combination of USB to Serial and vice-versa connection along with a standard AVR like the ATmega locked with a bootloader for easy programming over the USART, so feel free to use it like any other AVR.
You can use a Bluetooth like 2.1+EDR or 3.0 which I have tested with the latest Android devices and pc's (this includes BLE4.0 compatible phones too!) however should also be compatible with the iPhone as the phones have Bluetooth modules working on the dual mode which means they support BLE and conventional BLuetooth featues both.

A fine rotary encoder here >> https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9117
There are other assortment of encoders there too ,please check out!